# Writing a max cost algorithm that seems to always return 0. Why does it loop through the entire data set and only return '0'?

Tags: loops, iteration

This function goes through an array and returns the max cost

This is the .in file

it reads how many sets of data [3] and then how many elements in each set [4]; with P and E indicating initial position and ending position.

3 4

P 2 4 3

2 9 6 9

13 3 8 E

---

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.*;

  public class pacMan {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

  int row = stdin.nextInt();
  int col = stdin.nextInt();
  int[][] gameBoard = new int[row][col];
  String tempVal;

  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
      tempVal = stdin.next();

      if (tempVal.equals("P") || tempVal.equals("E"))
      {
        gameBoard[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        gameBoard[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tempVal);
      }

    }
  }


   System.out.println(maxCost(gameBoard, row, col));
 }







 public static int maxCost(int[][]cost, int m, int n ) {
```

This first loop calculates the path values for the outer edge across 
the top of the matrix

```
int temp[][] = new int[m][n]; //creates temp board to store path values
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
{
  temp[0][i] = sum + cost[0][i]; //adds the value of cost[0][i] to 0 
  and store it in the same postion in temp
  sum = temp[0][i]; //need to store temp value in sum as it will be 
added to the next path value
}
```

The second for loop calculates the path values for the outer left 
edge of the matrix

```
sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
{
  temp[i][0] = sum + cost[i][0];
  sum = temp[i][0];
}

/*Calculate the maxCost*/
```

I put in a print statement to row and column values for my temp. I think its printing the final value in temp but for some reason its not adding the value max function.

```
System.out.println("M=" + m + "\tN=" + n + "\ttemp.row=" + temp.length 
+ "\ttemp.col=" + temp[0].length);

for(int i=1; i < m; i++)
{
  for(int j=1; j < n; j++)
  {
    temp[i][j] = cost[i][j] + Math.max(temp[i-1][j], temp[i][j-1]);
  }
}
```

It should return 26 but it only returns 0

```
return temp[m][n];
}
```

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please have a look at: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Where do you define m and n?

Comment: Also, please clean up the code so that it is coherent. Add comments, such as `// first loop` and `// second loop` and then refer to the comments in your text when explaining the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues in your program:

(1) Your first `for` loop should be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

(2) Your second `for` loop should be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= m; i++)
```

(3) Finally, your `return` statement should be like this:

```
return temp[m - 1][n - 1];
```

Once you fix these issues, you should get the expected output.

Comment: Looks like you slightly beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

The first two loops that you have written are incorrect.

The first iterates with

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
```

The second iterates also iterates with

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
```

In both cases you will only update  `temp[0][0]`. You need to change the value within `i <= 0` to match either the height or width of your grid.

Additionally, the logic for setting the initial values of temp is incorrect.

Currently for both loops you have (or with 0 and i flipped):

```
temp[0][i] = sum + cost[0][i];
sum = temp[0][i];
```

This should instead be:

```
temp[0][i] = sum + cost[0][i];
sum += temp[0][i];
```

This will ensure that your cost grid is correctly initialized.

Finally, your return statement is incorrect.

It should be `return temp[m-1][n-1]` not `return temp[m][n]`